# Get text from XML string

Tags: php

I'm attempting to get the bulk diesel price for the latest date by xml file at http://www.fta.co.uk/feeds/daily_fuel_price.xml

I've used simplexml_load_string to get the channel item description, which is a string.

```
Latest fuel prices at 24 May 2016<p>86.28ppl<br>88.84ppl<br>39.31ppl<br></p><p>PricesfromAccenture</p>
```

I need this value `86.28ppl`, which is the bulk diesel price.  How do i get this. i've  tried explode with `<br>` and then explode again with `<p>` to try and put the value in array but it still display the full string.

How do i solve?

Here is the full code, try yourself

```
 $url = "http://www.fta.co.uk/feeds/daily_fuel_price.xml";
    if (($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($url))===false){
        echo "Error fetching XML\n";
    } else {
       libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
       $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
       if (!$data) {
           echo "Error loading XML\n";
           foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
               echo "\t", $error->message;
           }
       } else {
      //    echo "<pre>";
       //$data = simplexml_load_string($data->channel->item->description);
       foreach ($data->channel->item as $entry){
        echo $entry->title;
      //echo $entry->description;
      $str = preg_replace('#(<b.*?>).*?(</b>)#', '$1$2', $entry->description); //remove text between bold tags

      $str = str_replace("<b></b>","",$str); //remove bold tags
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);  //remove whitespace
   $arr = explode("<p>", $str);

    $arr = explode("<br>", $arr[1]);
    echo $arr[0];
      break;
       }
       //echo "</pre>";
       }
    }
```

Comment: explode with `<p>` and again explode the second part with `<br>` and collect the first part.

Comment: yes, i've used xml parser.  This is the item description.

Comment: The description in link is differ than one in the question. Maybe,  your problem is that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this: [Online Check](https://3v4l.org/QZ8Yg)

```
$str = 'Latest fuel prices at 24 May 2016<p>86.28ppl<br>88.84ppl<br>39.31ppl<br></p><p>PricesfromAccenture</p>';

$arr = explode("<p>", $str);

$arr = explode("<br>", $arr[1]);
echo $arr[0]; //86.28ppl
```

Comment: tried this and it doesn't work.  I think due to double quotations in `$str`

Comment: where you check?? Did you check the **Online Check**?? You just give the string and i apply some operation on it.

Comment: Try this link content: [https://3v4l.org/EnbhP](https://3v4l.org/EnbhP), The link won't work, just copy the content and run it in `phpfiddle`  or local machine

Comment: @user892134, are you done or need some more support? If done please mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `description` tag in the link is differ that one in the question. That, in the link, can be processed so:

```
  $arr = explode("<p>", $entry->description);
  $arr = explode("</b>", $arr[1]);
  $arr = explode("<br", $arr[1]);
  $desc = trim($arr[0]); // 86.28ppl
```